# Replacing multiple entires in a text file using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a structured text file containing a number of multi-line records. Each record should have a key unique field. I need to read through a series of these files, finding the non-unique key fields and replacing the key value with unique values.

My script is identifying all the fields which need replacing. I store these fields in a dictionary where the key is the non-unique field and the value is a list of unique values.

Eg:

```
 {
 "1111111111" : ["1234566363", "5533356775", "6443458343"]
 }
```

What I would like to do is read through each file just once, finding instances of "1111111111" (dict key) and replacing the first match with the first key value, second match with the second key value etc.

I am trying to use a regular expression but I am not sure how to construct a suitable RE without looping through the file multiple times

This is my current code:

```
def multireplace(Text, Vars):
    dictSorted = sorted(Vars, key=len, reverse=True)
    regEx = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, dictSorted)))
    return regEx.sub(lambda match: Vars[match.group(0)], Text)

text = multireplace(text, find_replace_dict)
```

It works fine for single key:value combinations but will fail to compile if the :value is a list:

```
return regEx.sub(lambda match: Vars[match.group(0)], Text , 1)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, list found
```

It is possible to alter the function without looping multiple times through a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look and read through the comments. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense:

```
import re

def replace(text, replacements):
    # Make a copy so we don't destroy the original.
    replacements = replacements.copy()

    # This is essentially what you had already.
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys())))

    # In our lambda, we pop the first element from the array. This way,
    # each time we're called with the same group, we'll get the next replacement.
    return regex.sub(lambda m: replacements[m.group(0)].pop(0), text)

print(replace("A A B B A B", {"A": ["A1", "A2", "A3"], "B": ["B1", "B2", "B3"]}))

# Output:
# A1 A2 B1 B2 A3 B3
```

**UPDATE**

To help with the issue in the comments below, try this version, which will tell you exactly which string ran out of replacements:

```
import re

def replace(text, replacements):

    # Let's make a method so we can do a little more than the lambda.
    def make_replacement(match):
        try:
            return replacements[match.group(0)].pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            # Print out debug info about what happened
            print("Ran out of replacements for {}".format(match.group(0)))
            # Re-raise so the process still exits.
            raise

    # Make a copy so we don't destroy the original.
    replacements = replacements.copy()

    # This is essentially what you had already.
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys())))

    # In our lambda, we pop the first element from the array. This way,
    # each time we're called with the same group, we'll get the next replacement.
    return regex.sub(make_replacement, text)

print(replace("A A B B A B A", {"A": ["A1", "A2", "A3"], "B": ["B1", "B2", "B3"]}))

# Output:
# A1 A2 B1 B2 A3 B3
```

Comment: This is failing for me with:   return regex.sub(lambda m: replacements[m.group(0)].pop(0), text)
IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: I am getting the text from a file with open(full_file_path,'r') as f: text = f.read(). Then passing text to the replace function with a dict.  Your code does seem to work for a single line of text though.

Comment: If you're getting `IndexError: pop from empty list` then it seems like you ran out of replacements for that particular string. (All of them were used already.)

Comment: See my edit for a different version of the code that will help you figure out which string is out of replacements. (This also gives you a good place to put in a default value or deal with the error some other way.)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the problem with my dict. Take all the fake internet points I can give you !